# Fsharp / how to change type Node of (string * FsTree) list into a list where 2paths cannot be identical

Tags: f#, filesystems, fscheck, fsharpchart

In FSharp, I would like to do the following

given a type :
`type FsTree = Node of (string * FsTree) list`

I would like to define a predicate 
toStringList so that : 
`toStringList myFsTree` gives the bellow result

result :

```
[
    ["n1"];
    ["n2"; "sub_n2_1"];
    ["n2"; "sub_n2_2"];
    ["n3"; "sub_n3"; "sub_sub_n3_1"];
    ["n3"; "sub_n3"; "sub_sub_n3_2"];
    ["n3"; "sub_n3"; "sub_sub_n3_3"];
    ["n4"];
]
```

Where

```
let myFsT = Node [
    ("n1", Node []); 
    ("n2", Node [
    ("sub_n2_1", Node []);
    ("sub_n2_2", Node [])
    ]); 
    ("n3", Node [
    ("sub_n3", Node [
    ("sub_sub_n3_1", Node []); 
    ("sub_sub_n3_2", Node []); 
    ("sub_sub_n3_3", Node []); 
    ])
    ]); 
    ("n4", Node [])
]
```

What I have done so far (here below)  is absolutely not correct, I know that. But I'm really stuck here! Does anyone have an idea what to do?

```
let rec test (fst:FsTree) = 
        match fst with
        | Node []              -> []
        | Node ((str, subFst)::restNode) -> 
            [[str] @ (test subFst)] @ (test restNode)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a tricky one because it requires 2 mutually recursive functions one for `Node` and one for the list inside `Node`.

```
let rec processNode     prepend node =
    let rec processList prepend listOfNodes =
        match   listOfNodes with
        | []                         -> []
        | (str, subNode) :: restList -> 
            let restList = processList  prepend restList
            let newPrepend = List.append prepend [ str ]
            match processNode newPrepend subNode with
            | []  -> [ newPrepend ]
            | lst -> lst
            @ restList
    match node with Node listOfNodes -> processList prepend listOfNodes

processNode [] myFsT
|> List.iter print
```

You need one recursive function to go over the elements in the list: `processList`

and another one to go over the subnodes in the list: `processNode`.

The confusion arises because all `processNode` does is get the list from `Node` and then call `processList` so it is easy to think of them as if they could be just one function.

OTOH, `processList` is double recursive. It calls itself to go over the elements of the list and it calls `processNode` to go deeper into the subtree.

There is also an accumulator parameter that needs to be passed which is `prepend` which carries the path.